# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Where is the embedded server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I just installed worklight studio 6.0, but I can't find the embedded worklight server that I used to test my application with. Instead there is change worklight target server. any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should familiarize yourself with all the changes introduced in Worklight 6.0.
You can read about that in the [IBM Worklight Information Center](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp).

In Worklight 6.0, Jetty is no longer used. Instead, the underlying application server is now WebSphere Liberty profile and with that many changes around it have been made and others introduced. As mentioned, familiarize yourself with the product.

Create a Worklight project and application as you would normally do. Run As >> Deploy... should then start the server.

If you want to just start the server, you can do that from the Servers view in Eclipse; you will see there an entry titled "Worklight Development Serer". Simply click the green play button to server the server.

Comment: I did create a new project, but the problem When I right click --run as -->deploy project to IPAS, and there is no other deployment option as it was in version 5.0.6.

Comment: All options still exist. Nothing was removed. Right-click on the app folder and choose Run As >> Build and Deploy.

Comment: If you still encounter issues, then start with a fresh, new, workspace. Also make sure you are using Eclipse Java EE 4.2.2(!).

Comment: @Nada, glad to hear; please mark this question as answered when possible.